# Get data from Bluetooth scale

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to get data from this type of scale
https://acaia.co/products/pearl. It does not show up under discover-able Bluetooth devices on a computer or phone, but it does have an app which it connects to automatically when turned on; the app can then display the weight in real time. This is my first time working with Bluetooth devices and am unsure as to how it is connecting to the app without showing up on other devices. Any information as to what is going on and possibly steps in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this connected to Arduino? Do you want to use one to communicate with the scale?

Comment: If you are sniffing with Microsoft Windows 10 you may want to stop.  Windows 10 is not a great platform to develop on.  It assumes many thing and does not tell the user about the assumptions.  [As of late (fall of 2019) Windows 10 will stop connecting to certain BlueTooth devices if Windows 10 thinks the devices are not safe to connect to](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2019/08/24/microsoft-windows-10-update-problem-bluetooth-warning-upgrade-windows-10/#4b9a132d67f2).

Comment: @chrisl yes, sorry the plan is to use an uno with a bluetooth module. We just want to have a way of getting the current weight on the scale

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is do some bluetooth sniffing to find out how the device is communicating with the phone. Here is a good article on doing that : http://nilhcem.com/iot/reverse-engineering-simple-bluetooth-devices